# Align the primary and secondary y-axis on the common base, set points in the center of bars?

Tags: r, plot, yaxis

I am trying to display barchart overlayed with line plot on secondary y-axis. I was following example here: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/r-graph-with-two-y-axes/. I successfully display my data, however the beginning of the y1 and y2 axis do not start on the common base (on the common 0), the y2 is located further up.

How to correctly align y1 and y2 axes on the common basis? Can I extent both of my y1 and y2 axis in the same size? And, how can I adjust the position of the points in the middle of the bars?

My dummy data:

```
x <- 1:5
y1 <- c(10,53,430,80,214)
y2 <- c(0.2,1.2,3.3, 3.5, 4.2)

# create new window 
windows()

# set margins
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
# create bar plot with primary axis (y1)
barplot(y1,  ylim= c(0,500))
mtext("y1",side=2,line=3)

# add plot with secondary (y2) axis
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y2,,type="b",col="red",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="", ylim= c(0,10), lwd = 2, lty = 2, pch = 18)
axis(4)
mtext("y2",side=4,line=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `yaxs = 'i'` to the second plot command.

Comment: coool, thank you !! can you please post this as an answer, that I can accept it?

Comment: Please, would you also have some suggestion how to place my "points" in the middle of my bars? I tried to play with xaxs in par() but I can't figure that out....

Comment: Added some information about that in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you check the documentation for `par()` you will find the options `xaxs`and `yaxs` with which you can control the interval calculation for both axes. Calling `par(yaxs = 'i')` prior to your `plot()` command or using the option directly as an argument to `plot()` will change the interval calculation in the following way:

> *Style "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels that fits
>   within the original data range.*

**Additional information for the TO concerning his comment:**

In order to center the points of the line go with `lines` instead and you can use the x-axis created by barplot:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
# create bar plot with primary axis (y1)
par(xpd = F)
ps <- barplot(y1,  ylim= c(0,500), xpd = F)
axis(4, at = 0:5 * 100, labels = 0:5 * 2)  # transform values
mtext('y1',side = 2, line = 3)
lines(x = ps, y = y2 * 50, type = 'b', col = 'red') # transform values
```